# How is Result<T, E> in Rust so fast?

Tags: performance, rust, memory, union, memory-alignment

If you have been online and active in the programming community within the last year, you've surely heard praise for Rust's execution speed and performance and also for the great `Result` type in Rust.

I should probably mention that I am not a Rust developer.
In spite of this, or maybe even because of this, I wonder how it can be that Rust can be so performant, if it uses this Result type, since as far as I'm concerned this type is implemented as what would be called an `union` in **C**. It includes within the union an Error and a return value of which only one is valid at a given time. The type also contains a flag that indicates whether the Result contains an error or a value.

If I have counted correctly, and operating under the assumption that the error is stored as a pointer or reference  (e.g. occupies 8 bytes in memory on 64-bit systems), then 8 bytes minimum for the union + one byte for the flag, makes 9 bytes of memory.

Now with padding I assume that on most systems this will be realigned to occupy 12 bytes.
Compared to that returning an int(32) only allocates 4 bytes. Using Result should thus allocate thrice as much memory as using an int.

Isn't this an extreme waste of memory? I imagine running this in a loop, that would add up quite a bit.

I cannot quite see how anyone can claim that Rust is super performant while Result takes up that much memory?

I am aware that there are a few optimization tricks that can decrease memory usage, like using a NotZeroInt with an option enables the compiler to use zero as the flag, thereby avoiding having an extra byte for the flag. But for most types this isn't applicable, is it?

If anyone has further insight, I would love to hear it.
Please be aware that I am not a Rust developer, and am asking this question out of curiosity, as I have observed in libraries that try to port this feature that the memory usage increases drastically.

Surely Rust's `Result<T, E>` and `Option<T>` types are better optimized than some ported libraries, but I cannot imagine how this doesn't impact program performance.

Comment: E is generic and the source code of the standard library shows it stored inline. Why do you assume it would be stored behind a pointer or a reference?

Comment: Why are you "operating under the assumption" when you can check the definition of [`Result`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/core/result.rs.html#502) to see that there's no pointer or reference

Comment: It might be additionally useful to see examples of these unperformant ports so that answers can make comparisons and show why the performance difference happens.

Comment: I think the reason for the downvotes is that the assumptions in this question could've been easily proven false if you had simply checked the result of `std::mem::size_of` on several `Result` types to see how big they are. It's generally better to prove your assumptions true or false _before_ you ask a question predicated on them.

Comment: I could've done that in fact, yes,  but as I mentioned, I was just curious, I don't have rust installed on my system anywhere..

Comment: @dragon the rust playground (which I used in one of my comments on the answer since I don't have rust on my smartphone) is a great resource if you want to play around further without installing anything.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You seem to be familiar with APIs that return integers to report exit status: zero for successes and non-zero for failures. An API expressing the same thing in idiomatic Rust will achieve the same or better performance<sup>1</sup> while being more type safe.

The first step is to use `Result` to classify the value as a success or failure. Since we don't need to return anything additional in the successful case, we use `()`:

```
Result<(), i32>
```

With this, it does use more space than a simple `i32` since at least one bit of information is needed to convey the success. Though to address one of your misconceptions, there is no pointer indirection for the error value; it is stored in-line. So this would be 4 bytes for `i32` + 1 byte for discriminant + 3 bytes of padding to achieve 4-byte alignment = 8 bytes.

As you've mentioned, using `NonZeroI32` is an option:

```
Result<(), NonZeroI32>
```

That could be potentially more clear anyway (receiving `Err(0)` may otherwise be confusing if you're used to zero expressing success) and gives `Result` one extra bit of information such that the size is now only 4 bytes total since the compiler can use the all-zero bit-pattern that is unused by `NonZeroI32` to express success.

However that is still not really idiomatic Rust since `NonZeroI32` is not particularly refined. More often than not you'll have an error type defined as an enum of error cases:

```
enum MySimpleError {
    FailureA,
    FailureB,
    FailureC,
}
```

```
Result<(), MySimpleError>
```

This is now much more expressive since it is now encoded in the type what values can exist and is even smaller since `MyError` has way less than 256 variants so it can be encoded as a single byte with bit-patterns to spare such that the whole `Result` is a single byte.

<sup>1. It is not likely that values less than a machine word size actually improve performance - only by potentially reducing memory pressure if it can be stored with other small values.</sup>

---

Another common pattern: sometimes error types can get very large (trying to provide as much useful information as possible) but are not common - or at least should not be. In this case you may wish to introduce indirection via `Box` for the error type to keep the on-stack size down.

```
Result<(), Box<MyComplexError>>
```

This will be a machine word size since `Box` is guaranteed to not be null, and thus the all-zero bit-pattern can be used for the success case just as is possible with `NonZeroI32`.

You may find that libraries may do this internally already. For example, the `Error` from serde-json looks like this:

```
/// This type represents all possible errors that can occur when serializing or
/// deserializing JSON data.
pub struct Error {
    /// This `Box` allows us to keep the size of `Error` as small as possible. A
    /// larger `Error` type was substantially slower due to all the functions
    /// that pass around `Result<T, Error>`.
    err: Box<ErrorImpl>,
}
```

```
Result<(), serde_json::Error> // does not use any extra space
```

---

Of course there are plenty of cases where additional space for the discriminant *must* be used - either due to the success type, error type, or both - but that is simply a necessity to express the data you wish to return. Even if an extra machine word is needed, handling errors in this manner is often more efficient overall than the cost of throwing exceptions should an error occur.

Answer (score 0):

Rust is a lot more intelligent and optimized about how it allocates enum discriminants than C can be with tagged unions, because there is no way to access them directly. Additionally, Rust has generics as a native functionality, which means that the Result<T, E> layout is separately defined and and optimized for every combination of T and E used.

Because of the generics, there is no need to use a reference, the values are contained directly within the union of the Result Enum. This means that the minimum in most cases where the error is an error code is Error + Flag which is 2 bytes. (one for the Error discriminant, and one for the Flag discriminant).

However, you also need to be able to return a value, and that value is the normal case. That value often has padding and is larger than the error value. If this is the case, the rust compiler is able to use padding for the discriminator for the result, resulting in a tagged enum that is effective the same size as its largest value. This gives you effectively free Result objects in terms of memory usage.

Comment: I agree with two bytes for the most part, but a [one byte Error](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=e84e1abac139de0e34281f7e4823032e) might be worth showing to the OP and other readers as far as the kinds of optimizations that are possible under the right conditions.

Comment: Yeah, ok, makes sense, I suppossed, that there would be a reference for the error, which clearly is not really necessary.

Comment: Then how do you go about error messages?? They are references???

Comment: it depends on the error type. Options include providing a function that maps error code to error message (the same as you would with a C error code), or you can include a enum variant containing a reference. If you do that, then the minimum size will likely end up as at least 24 bytes on a 64 bit system, but that only matters if your T type isn't also at least 24 bytes in size, which it usually would be. The data will need to be conveyed somehow, and rust gives you a number of possibilities depending on the situation.